# Install sdkman on Amazon Linux 2: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-linux-2, sdkman

I'm trying to install sdkman on an Amazon Linux 2 AMI (I have no choice, we must use some blessed/patched AMIs). I follow the steps:

```
sudo curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

No errors so far. But then I run:

```
sdk version
```

And I get:

```
/home/ec2-user/.sdkman/libexec/version: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /home/ec2-user/.sdkman/libexec/version)
```

I didn't find previous versions of sdkman... Amazon Linux2 uses glibc 2.26. yum updating to 2.28 is porbably going to hose the system... What can I do?!?

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xxx-vvv-ssss ~]$ yum info glibc
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
224 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Installed Packages
Name        : glibc
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.26
Release     : 63.amzn2
Size        : 13 M
Repo        : installed
Summary     : The GNU libc libraries
URL         : http://www.gnu.org/software/glibc/
License     : LGPLv2+ and LGPLv2+ with exceptions and GPLv2+
Description : The glibc package contains standard libraries which are used by
            : multiple programs on the system. In order to save disk space and
            : memory, as well as to make upgrading easier, common system code is
            : kept in one place and shared between programs. This particular package
            : contains the most important sets of shared libraries: the standard C
            : library and the standard math library. Without these two libraries, a
            : Linux system will not function.

Available Packages
Name        : glibc
Arch        : i686
Version     : 2.26
Release     : 63.amzn2
Size        : 4.1 M
Repo        : amzn2-core/2/x86_64
Summary     : The GNU libc libraries
URL         : http://www.gnu.org/software/glibc/
License     : LGPLv2+ and LGPLv2+ with exceptions and GPLv2+
Description : The glibc package contains standard libraries which are used by
            : multiple programs on the system. In order to save disk space and
            : memory, as well as to make upgrading easier, common system code is
            : kept in one place and shared between programs. This particular package
            : contains the most important sets of shared libraries: the standard C
            : library and the standard math library. Without these two libraries, a
            : Linux system will not function.
```